Help with understanding combination of probability distributions
I have two probability mass functions (PMFs) across the surface of a sphere. They are localised Gaussians (a few degrees in expanse), whose centres have arbitrary positions though they are quite close to each other. I believe them to be 'signals' correlated to the same source event, though they are by no means identical. This source events has to occur at some point between them. I'd like to create a PMF of where this source could be, based upon my original PMFs. Is a convolution the correct way to do this?
Unnecessary but maybe useful info: physically, the two PMFs represent gamma ray burst (GRB) localisations and I am assuming that they are gravitationally strongly lensed images of the same source GRB.
